# Deploy from Git using Capistrano without a hard reset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I've an issue at the moment where we are running a CMS within a site
(browsercms) that lets the user upload files.  However, every time I
do a deploy Capistrano runs a hard reset thus nuking any uploaded
files.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to prevent the hard reset,
and just do a pull, or a way of moving the uploaded files elsewhere,
without having to change the application code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the right approach.

You should include your 'images' folder in your .gitignore and symlink the $current_release/images folder to $shared/images.

This may be done automatically on every deployment if you put in your deploy.rb:

```
task :link_imgs do     
  run "ln -s #{shared_path}/photos #{release_path}/photos" 
end    

after "deploy:update_code", :link_imgs
```

I've done the same with my CMS and it works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't quite meet your criteria of "without having to change the application code".

However after running into a similar issue I shifted my uploaded image from `/public/images` to `/public/system/images` the `/public/system` directory is not 'versioned' by each capistrano deployment so the images survive.

Could it be the capistrano 'versioning' causing the problem *(instead of a git reset)*?

Comment: Ah yes, you might be right there.  It may be that I need to make the uploads directory a 'shared' one.

Comment: This is the preferred Capistrano solution, which is why it symlinks current/public/system to shared/system by default.  Paperclip and some other plugins store things here by default for that rason, too.  AttachmentFu managed models will need the "upload_path" changed per model.

Answer (score 0):

*cap deploy* calls *deploy:update* and *deploy:restart*

*deploy:update* makes the versioning, copying stuff

*deploy:restart* does the true restart, overload it at your convenince, usually in your **config/deploy.rb** file

```
namespace :deploy do
    desc "Softly restart the server"
    task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      my_own.restart_recipe
    end  
end
```